# Не запускается бот, без ошибок, js

Tags: javascript, discord, бот

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Подключаем библиотеку discord.js
const robot = new Discord.Client(); // Объявляем, что robot - бот
const comms = require("./comms.js"); // Подключаем файл с командами для бота
const fs = require('fs'); // Подключаем родной модуль файловой системы node.js  
let config = require('./config.json'); // Подключаем файл с параметрами и информацией
let token = config.token; // «Вытаскиваем» из него токен
let prefix = config.prefix; // «Вытаскиваем» из него префикс

robot.on("ready", function() {
  /* При успешном запуске, в консоли появится сообщение «[Имя бота] запустился!» */
  console.log(robot.user.username + "Catix запустился!");
});


robot.on('message', (msg) => { // Реагирование на сообщения
  if (msg.author.username != robot.user.username && msg.author.discriminator != robot.user.discriminator) {
    var comm = msg.content.trim() + " ";
    var comm_name = comm.slice(0, comm.indexOf(" "));
    var messArr = comm.split(" ");
    for (comm_count in comms.comms) {
      var comm2 = prefix + comms.comms[comm_count].name;
      if (comm2 == comm_name) {
        comms.comms[comm_count].out(robot, msg, messArr);
      }
    }
  }
});


robot.login(token); // Авторизация бота
```

После этого пишу note bot.js - ни чего не происходит.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доп коды:
comms.js

```
const config = require('./config.json'); // Подключаем файл с параметрами и информацией
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Подключаем библиотеку discord.js
const prefix = config.prefix; // «Вытаскиваем» префикс

// Команды //

function test(robot, mess, args) {
  mess.channel.send('Test!')
}


// Список команд //

var comms_list = [{
  name: "test",
  out: test,
  about: "Тестовая команда"
}];

// Name - название команды, на которую будет реагировать бот
// Out - название функции с командой
// About - описание команды 

module.exports.comms = comms_list;
```

config.js

```
{
    "token" : "ODY4NjE1MTU4MjEyMTk4NDEw.YPyO5w.W_qUezQJSIjh93aFCqfYhoD",
    "prefix" : "!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

При логине можно вывести в консоль ошибки

```
robot.login(token).then(()=>{console.log('Bot logined')}).catch((e)=>{console.log(`Bot error: ${e}`)});
```